# Not able to import the intl package for dart

Tags: dart, flutter

Hi I am trying to use the intl package in my flutter project. The packages get command runs successfully but when I import the package it shows error.

[image: My pubspec.yaml file]

For the import in the my dart file I am using the following import

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
```

I have also upgraded flutter from the terminal using the flutter upgrade command.

Comment: What error does it show?

Comment: No it doesn't print any error. I get the following:

C:\Users\personal\flutter\bin\flutter.bat --no-color packages get
Running "flutter packages get" in quake_report...
Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: While importing it says target uri doesn't exist.

Comment: Have you tried restarting your IDE.

Comment: thanks man. Restarting the IDE worked for me.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Here are some steps that I offten see as problems with dependencies in flutter.

1. The thing with `pubspec.yaml` is that you have to save it CRTL/CMD + S before pub get will work. Running pub get from IDE doesn't save the file automatically.
2. Try running `flutter clean` and then run `flutter pub get`.
   Sometimes when you remove dependencies like plugins, `.build` folder doesnt get cleaned up properly so you have to do it manually.
3. You can try to repair pub cache by running `flutter pub cache repair`
4. Sometimes just restarting your IDE might solve the problem as well.

Comment: have you tried to run flutter clean, and than pub get?

Comment: then, if this doesnt work you can try pub cache repair

Comment: I tried all of the above but it didn't work for me. But thanks for writing that solution. I can try these steps next time if I am stuck.

Restarting the IDE worked for me as @Gunter told

Comment: no problem, I wrote them down cause I see this pop up alot and usually this steps fix the problems

Comment: I added @gunter solution as well, so it stays

Comment: Restarting the IDE is much more powerful than you would expect.

Answer (score 4):

It needs to reload the flowing package using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> might not work sometimes. Need to restart IDE after saving `pubspec.yaml` file.

Comment: Tried all the terminal commands didn't work. Ctrl + S worked. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

After the project cleaning you could have some error like this:

```
intl_browser.dart:13:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:html'
```

You can clean your cache, make all you want to refresh your flutter project:

```
- flutter clean 
- rm -rf pubspec.lock .packages .flutter-plugins 
- flutter pub pub cache repair
- flutter packages get
```

But you can't solve until you comment this line on your code :

```
findSystemLocale()
```

This line is in conflict with `dart:html` as you can see here below according with the current `intl` source:

```
library intl_browser;

import "dart:async";
import "dart:html";
import "intl.dart";

// TODO(alanknight): The need to do this by forcing the user to specially
// import a particular library is a horrible hack, only done because there
// seems to be no graceful way to do this at all. Either mirror access on
// dart2js or the ability to do spawnUri in the browser would be promising
// as ways to get rid of this requirement.
/// Find the system locale, accessed as window.navigator.language, and
/// set it as the default for internationalization operations in the
/// [Intl.systemLocale] variable.
Future<String> findSystemLocale() {
  Intl.systemLocale = Intl.canonicalizedLocale(window.navigator.language);
  return new Future.value(Intl.systemLocale);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Faced the same issue, if you are importing

```
import "package:intl/intl_browser.dart";
```

then you will get that error, it seems like the dart SDK bundled with flutter does not have the required dependencies.

So use only

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
```

and it should work just fine.

Answer (score 3):

It started working for me after I inserted one tab before 'intl'. Final set of code looks here...

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3
  intl: ^0.16.1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to be able to use `findSystemLocale()` on both web and other platforms, you can use conditional import:

```
import 'package:intl/intl_standalone.dart' if (dart.library.html) 'package:intl/intl_browser.dart';
```

After that you can just write

```
Intl.defaultLocale = await findSystemLocale();
```

You will be able to build on any platform.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on Visual Studio Code with the latest stable version of flutter. none of the previous answers helped in my case.

Running `pub cache repair`, which was suggested by some of the answers, used up all my data since it started downloading all flutter packages **regardless of whether I used them or not** and didn't solve anything.

**The solution that worked for me:**

Instead of running `flutter pub get package_name` in the terminal, I had to add the package under the dependencies in "pubspec.yaml" file manually like so:

```
dependencies:
   package_name: ^1.1.0
```

and save it.

After saving it the IDE would get the packages for me and everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it with a combination of things from this question and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56575071/project-doesnt-compile-when-using-intl-package-dateformat).

Firstly, import `intl_standalone` in your `main.dart`, not `intl_browser`.

```
import 'package:intl/date_symbol_data_local.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl_standalone.dart';
```

Then call the necessary setup function, like this:

```
void main() async {
  Intl.defaultLocale = await findSystemLocale();
  await initializeDateFormatting();
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Make sure to add intl to your deps, like this:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  intl:
```

Then run the following commands in order from your project directory:

```
flutter clean 
rm -rf pubspec.lock .packages .flutter-plugins 
flutter pub cache repair
flutter pub get
```

With this I could get it to work when building to Android and iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Bit late but this happened to me, check the name of your files isn't the same name as the package you want to import.

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me by manually adding **intl: ^0.18.0** in pubspec.yaml and saving it **(Cmd+S)**.

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  intl: ^0.18.0
```

Wherever required import as **import 'package:intl/intl.dart';**