# Project doesn't compile when using Intl package (DateFormat)

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to run my app after importing [intl](https://pub.dev/packages/intl/install), but it won't work.

In the `pubspec.yaml` file I have:

```
intl: ^0.15.8
```

I've imported the package in three ways after some research, just to be sure. But only the first one (intl.dart) seems to be used  :

```
import "package:intl/intl.dart";
import "package:intl/intl_browser.dart"; //unused import
import "package:intl/intl_standalone.dart"; //unused import
```

I'm using it this way :

```
DateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format(_chosenDate)
```

My error after `flutter run` is:

```
Resolving dependencies...                                           2,3s
                                                                        
Compiler message:                                                       
file:///Users/mydomus/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/intl-0.15.8/lib/intl_browser.dart:25:48: Error: Getter not found: 'window'.
  Intl.systemLocale = Intl.canonicalizedLocale(window.navigator.language);
                                               ^^^^^^                   
file:///Users/mydomus/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/intl-0.15.8/lib/intl_browser.dart:13:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:html'
import "dart:html";                                                     
       ^                                                                
Unhandled exception:                                                    
FileSystemException(uri=org-dartlang-untranslatable-uri:dart%3Ahtml; message=StandardFileSystem only supports file:* and data:* URIs)
#0      StandardFileSystem.entityForUri (package:front_end/src/api_prototype/standard_file_system.dart:33:7)
#1      asFileUri (package:vm/kernel_front_end.dart:589:37)             
<asynchronous suspension>                                               
#2      FrontendCompiler._outputDependenciesDelta (package:vm/frontend_server.dart:391:39)
<asynchronous suspension>                                               
#3      FrontendCompiler.compile (package:vm/frontend_server.dart:365:13)
<asynchronous suspension>                                               
#4      _FlutterFrontendCompiler.compile (package:frontend_server/server.dart:31:22)
<asynchronous suspension>                                               
#5      starter (package:frontend_server/server.dart:133:27)            
<asynchronous suspension>                                               
#6      main (file:///b/s/w/ir/k/src/flutter/frontend_server/bin/starter.dart:8:30)
<asynchronous suspension>                                               
#7      _startIsolate.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:298:32)
#8      _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:171:12)
                                                                        
Compiler failed on /Users/mydomus/Desktop/meriem/flutter/mydomus_edl/lib/main.dart
```

Am I doing something wrong? or is it a package issue that I should report?

Comment: Does it run in a new flutter project? Maybe check `flutter doctor -v` for errors

Comment: I believe the following unused import is the cause and not the dateformat one. 

`import "package:intl/intl_browser.dart"; //unused import`

Try removing this

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59310849/3268303

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it by changing the import. Instead of importing:

```dart
import "package:intl/intl_browser.dart";
```

import the following:

```dart
import 'package:intl/intl_standalone.dart';
```

Answer (score 11):

This is because you have an import of "dart:html", but it doesn't exist on the platform you are deploying to.

See this line in the exception you posted:

```
import "dart:html";
```

This is a similar issue:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/59310849/3268303

Answer (score 3):

I was also getting this error. Just run the command `flutter clean`.
After running this command the issue was solved.

Answer (score 0):

The import from the [intl](https://pub.dev/packages/intl/install) package of `import "package:intl/intl_browser.dart";`, tries using the [`dart:html`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-html/dart-html-library.html) package which is not configured.

---

Use the following import instead:

```
import 'package:intl/intl_standalone.dart';
```

Answer (score 0):

To be able to support both web and other platforms without need to edit the source code you can use conditional import:

```
import 'package:intl/intl_standalone.dart' if (dart.library.html) 'package:intl/intl_browser.dart';
```

Then just

```
Intl.defaultLocale = await findSystemLocale();
```