# Flutter - Dart failing after Android Studio and Flutter update

Tags: flutter, dart, compiler-errors

I had a project that was running without issues and, since I updated to `Android Studio 3.5.3` and `Flutter 1.13.1-pre.99 • channel master`, the same project gives a huge error when trying to run on real device.

I am mentioning here Android Studio and Flutter updates because I am not sur which of them (if any) is causing the problems.

It looks to me like a problem with `flutter_web` that I installed some time ago...but still Im not sure how to uninstall flutter_web itself.

**NOTE: the current project is NOT a flutter web project**

Here the complete error...(sorry for the huge text):

```
Invalid depfile: /Users/user458395/Desktop/flutterProjects/testProjectX/.dart_tool/flutter_build/0732b8ad26463ce096dc3cab1564707e/kernel_snapshot.d
Invalid depfile: /Users/user458395/Desktop/flutterProjects/testProjectX/.dart_tool/flutter_build/0732b8ad26463ce096dc3cab1564707e/kernel_snapshot.d

Compiler message:
lib/routes/search_results_route.dart:1:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:html'
import 'dart:html';
       ^
../../../Downloads/flutterSdk/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/http-0.12.0+2/lib/src/browser_client.dart:6:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:html'
import 'dart:html';
       ^
../../../Downloads/flutterSdk/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/http-0.12.0+2/lib/src/browser_client.dart:97:25: Error: Type 'HttpRequest' not found.
  void _openHttpRequest(HttpRequest request, String method, String url,
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../Downloads/flutterSdk/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/http-0.12.0+2/lib/src/browser_client.dart:32:25: Error: 'HttpRequest' isn't a type.
  final _xhrs = new Set<HttpRequest>();
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../Downloads/flutterSdk/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/_network_image_web.dart:64:12: Error: Method not found: 'webOnlyInstantiateImageCodecFromUrl'.
    return ui.webOnlyInstantiateImageCodecFromUrl(resolved) as Future<ui.Codec>; // ignore: undefined_function
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../Downloads/flutterSdk/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/http-0.12.0+2/lib/src/browser_client.dart:46:19: Error: Method not found: 'HttpRequest'.
    var xhr = new HttpRequest();
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../Downloads/flutterSdk/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/http-0.12.0+2/lib/src/browser_client.dart:57:45: Error: Method not found: 'Blob'.
      var blob = xhr.response == null ? new Blob([]) : xhr.response;
                                            ^^^^
../../../Downloads/flutterSdk/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/http-0.12.0+2/lib/src/browser_client.dart:58:24: Error: Method not found: 'FileReader'.
      var reader = new FileReader();
                       ^^^^^^^^^^
../../../Downloads/flutterSdk/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/http-0.12.0+2/lib/src/browser_client.dart:97:25: Error: 'HttpRequest' isn't a type.
  void _openHttpRequest(HttpRequest request, String method, String url,
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^
Unhandled exception:
FileSystemException(uri=org-dartlang-untranslatable-uri:dart%3Ahtml; message=StandardFileSystem only supports file:* and data:* URIs)
#0      StandardFileSystem.entityForUri (package:front_end/src/api_prototype/standard_file_system.dart:33:7)
#1      asFileUri (package:vm/kernel_front_end.dart:604:37)
#2      writeDepfile (package:vm/kernel_front_end.dart:799:21)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      FrontendCompiler.compile (package:frontend_server/frontend_server.dart:472:15)
<asynchronous suspension>
#4      _FlutterFrontendCompiler.compile (package:flutter_frontend_server/server.dart:38:22)
#5      starter (package:flutter_frontend_server/server.dart:149:27)
#6      main (file:///b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/flutter/flutter_frontend_server/bin/starter.dart:8:30)
#7      _startIsolate.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:305:32)
#8      _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:174:12)

Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception: Errors during snapshot creation: null
build failed.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script '/Users/user458395/Downloads/flutterSdk/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 792

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command '/Users/user458395/Downloads/flutterSdk/flutter/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 36s
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**EDIT**: to get rid from this issue switch back to stable channel by running this command in the terminal.

```
flutter channel stable
```

run `flutter upgrade` after this.

---

Please check detailed error by this command

```
flutter run --debug
```

**Point to remember: if its not a web project then Find and remove `dart:html`.**

> dart:html library is for web apps only (it wraps the DOM APIs) and it is not supposed run in Flutter.
> Please check [this git issue](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/36318)

Comment: how do i get rid of flutter web??

Comment: stable or master? you mention master in your comment but you say stable in your answer, as you can see in my question, I am already in master

Comment: My bad you need to switch back to stable by running this command into terminal `flutter channel stable`

Comment: working after changing to the stable channel, thanks!

Comment: What if I need dart:html for the web part ?

Answer (score 16):

Find `dart:html` in your project and remove it.

Then run `flutter clean`.

In my case, for some unknown reason, at some point my IDE (VSCode) created that import in one of my files, without me noticing.

Answer (score 12):

Running:

```
flutter clean
```

and then

```
flutter run --debug
```

Worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the import `'dart:html';` statement in the file 'lib/routes/search_results_route.dart' this was added without your knowledge and is the cause of the error

Answer (score 1):

Just by upgrading flutter the problem was solved:

```
flutter upgrade
```

Answer (score 1):

make sure you are on the stable channel of the current flutter version by running this command
`flutter channel stable`

then after `flutter upgrade` and `flutter clean` all this in your terminal then lastly,

go to your root dir `cd ~` after that run this command `rm -rf .gradle` then after all that finally run `flutter run --debug` under your flutter project root directory

Comment: make sure you have a stable internet connect after rm -rf .gradle because the Gradle files with have to be downloaded as the command above deleted the corrupted files

Answer (score 0):

Even use the stable branch, still the same issue:
`flutter --version Flutter 1.17.5 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git Framework • revision 8af6b2f038 (4 weeks ago) • 2020-06-30 12:53:55 -0700 Engine • revision ee76268252 Tools • Dart 2.8.4`

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I tried thousands of times flutter upgrade/pub get and etc. But in my case, the problem was in files where I imported ACCIDENLY packages that depend on flutter_web_plugins. The packages that depend on it usually have the name web/cloud so if you are using vscode just query in your files "web" or "cloud" or "dart:html/dart:js" . and remove it. In my case, it was "import "cloud_firestore_web"". removing that line solved my problem.